# Probit and transforming z-scores in gurobi (price optimization)

Tags: python, gurobi, scipy-optimize

For a course in university, I am trying to optimize the price I charge customers by finding the expected price that they will accept (price * probability of accepting that price). I am using Gurobi, and I use the probit parameters calculated with historical data, but using these parameters give me a z-score. I am unable to associate the probit z score to the probability (as the normal distribution that is installed in Python won't work within Gurobi function). This is my current idea, but it will not work, where I simply associate it using a dictionary of z-scores to probabilities in a 0,1 normal. I need the `prob[r]` to be manipulated in a nonlinear way (either using `st.norm.cdf(z)`) or to be rounded so I can associate it to a probability. I know it depends on the price, which is the variable, so I do not know if it is possible.
Any ideas or suggestions would be helpful.

```py
import numpy as np

demanda_0 = pd.DataFrame(
     data={
          'antiguedad': (0.805262, 0.775366, 1.313498, 0.919934, 0.904917),
          'maritimo':       (True,    False,    False,     True,    False),
          'express':       (False,    False,     True,    False,    False),
          'aereo':         (False,     True,    False,    False,     True),
          'porcentaje_quotestage_1': (
                         0.728624, 0.987425, 1.083067, 0.353984, 0.529083),
     },
     index=pd.RangeIndex(name='id', start=1, stop=6),
)

m = gp.Model("Optimizar Precios Logistica", env=env)

R = demanda_0

M = 10000000

p = m.addVars(demanda_0.index, name="p", lb=0, ub=M) 

prob = m.addVars(demanda_0.index, name="prob")

for r in demanda_0.index:
    prob[r] = (
        demanda_0.loc[r, 'antiguedad'] * 0.569396 +
        demanda_0.loc[r, 'maritimo'] *  -0.913858  +
        demanda_0.loc[r, 'express'] * -0.165595 +
        demanda_0.loc[r, 'aereo'] * 0.030166 +
        demanda_0.loc[r, 'porcentaje_quotestage_1'] * 1.687747 + p[r] * -0.000523
    )

dic = {
    -3.0: 0.00134989803163,
    -2.9: 0.00191172318706,
    -2.8: 0.00255513033018,
    -2.7: 0.00328943185389,
    -2.6: 0.00411565636173,
    -2.5: 0.00499750254617,
    -2.4: 0.00589875012553,
    -2.3: 0.00677566432527,
    -2.2: 0.00758899513659,
    -2.1: 0.00830839268624,
    -2.0: 0.0227501319482,
    -1.9: 0.01439744676436,
    -1.8: 0.01694742458357,
    -1.7: 0.01927575795789,
    -1.6: 0.02138602513441,
    -1.5: 0.02320922075231,
    -1.4: 0.02468234407296,
    -1.3: 0.02574798628676,
    -1.2: 0.02635515681939,
    -1.1: 0.02648322768712,
    -1.0: 0.158655253931,
    -0.9: 0.13566606094638,
    -0.8: 0.115069670221708,
    -0.7: 0.09680048458561,
    -0.6: 0.08075665923377,
    -0.5: 0.0668072012689,
    -0.4: 0.05479929169956,
    -0.3: 0.04456546275861,
    -0.2: 0.03593031911293,
    -0.1: 0.02871655981669,
    0.0: 0.5,
    0.1: 0.97128344018331,
    0.2: 0.96406968088707,
    0.3: 0.95543453724139,
    0.4: 0.94520070830044,
    0.5: 0.933192798731,
    0.6: 0.91924334076623,
    0.7: 0.90319951541439,
    0.8: 0.88493032977829,
    0.9: 0.86433393905362,
    1.0: 0.841344746069,
    1.1: 0.81582322731288,
    1.2: 0.78774581318061,
    1.3: 0.75798570450511,
    1.4: 0.72653065592704,
    1.5: 0.69314716055995,
    1.6: 0.65730019884867,
    1.7: 0.61839905914769,
    1.8: 0.57580633124096,
    1.9: 0.52892412654495,
    2.0: 0.47724986805182,
    2.1: 0.42074060762631,
    2.2: 0.35989164330376,
    2.3: 0.29505515613991,
    2.4: 0.22662735261643,
    2.5: 0.15597429781556,
    2.6: 0.08434363882874,
    2.7: 0.01390377072986,
    2.8: 0.00176703586613,
    2.9: 0.00023288832156,
    3.0: 0.00003167155677
}


# Creamos una variable binaria que indica si se acepta o no el precio
bin_var = m.addVars(demanda_0.index, name="bin_var", vtype=GRB.BINARY)

# Creamos el costo variable
cost = m.addVars(demanda_0.index, name="cost")

c_value = 117  
for r in demanda_0.index:
    cost[r] = c_value

#for r in demanda_0.index:
 #   m.addConstr(bin_var[r] >= prob[r] + 0.5) #this would require probability, not z-score from prob.

# Add constraints to ensure that p is 0 when bin_var is 0
for r in demanda_0.index:
    m.addConstr(p[r] >= cost[r] * bin_var[r])

m.update()
# Set the objective function
m.ModelSense = GRB.MAXIMIZE
m.setObjective(sum(p[r] * dic[prob[r]] for r in demanda_0.index))

# Optimize the model
m.optimize()
```

I tried using scipy to find the probability, and also the round function, neither will work, and it is important to note that prob depends on price.

Demanda0:
[Head of demand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwU3X.png)

Example of demand (R):

| id | antiguedad | maritimo | express | aereo | porcentaje_quotestage_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.790341 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1.229479 |
| 2 | 1.018066 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0.622855 |
| 3 | 0.970457 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1.049945 |
| 4 | 0.900848 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1.001532 |
| 5 | 0.898585 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1.090027 |

Comment: I have questions about the construction of the LP; let's please continue in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255928/probit-and-transforming-z-scores-in-gurobi-price-optimization

Comment: I cannot comment in the chat room as I dont have enough stackoverflow points

Comment: No, a non assigned row should have probability 0

Comment: It should be probability 0, therefore a z-score of -3.4 or lower

Comment: OK. I interpret this as: the price is only constrained when assigned; the dictionary is a map of z-values to probabilities; and when unassigned the probability (and thus the expected price) is 0.

Comment: Yes,  exactly. This is what I am hoping happens, but I cannot transform the z-score to the mapped probability.

Answer (score 0):

> price * probability of accepting that price

That should be captured in a decision variable, the expected price.

> I am using Gurobi

I do not have Gurobi so I demonstrate in PuLP. All of the concepts are transferable.

> using these parameters give me a z-score

You can model the z-score as an affine expression resulting from the matrix product of your lookup table's z-score values and a binary selection matrix.

> the normal distribution that is installed in Python won't work within Gurobi function

Your distribution is certainly not a normal distribution, so even if it did work it would not be appropriate. You can still capture your lookup table using selection variables.

> I need the prob[r] to be manipulated in a nonlinear way

Well, no. You need to approximate non-linear behaviour in a linear way.

```py
# Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77470565/probit-and-transforming-z-scores-in-gurobi-price-optimization

import numpy as np
import pulp
import pandas as pd


def make_distribution() -> tuple[
    np.ndarray,  # z scores
    pd.Series,   # probabilities
]:
    distribution = {
         -3.0: 0.00134989803163,
         -2.9: 0.00191172318706,
         -2.8: 0.00255513033018,
         -2.7: 0.00328943185389,
         -2.6: 0.00411565636173,
         -2.5: 0.00499750254617,
         -2.4: 0.00589875012553,
         -2.3: 0.00677566432527,
         -2.2: 0.00758899513659,
         -2.1: 0.00830839268624,
         -2.0: 0.0227501319482,
         -1.9: 0.01439744676436,
         -1.8: 0.01694742458357,
         -1.7: 0.01927575795789,
         -1.6: 0.02138602513441,
         -1.5: 0.02320922075231,
         -1.4: 0.02468234407296,
         -1.3: 0.02574798628676,
         -1.2: 0.02635515681939,
         -1.1: 0.02648322768712,
         -1.0: 0.158655253931,
         -0.9: 0.13566606094638,
         -0.8: 0.115069670221708,
         -0.7: 0.09680048458561,
         -0.6: 0.08075665923377,
         -0.5: 0.0668072012689,
         -0.4: 0.05479929169956,
         -0.3: 0.04456546275861,
         -0.2: 0.03593031911293,
         -0.1: 0.02871655981669,
         0.0: 0.5,
         0.1: 0.97128344018331,
         0.2: 0.96406968088707,
         0.3: 0.95543453724139,
         0.4: 0.94520070830044,
         0.5: 0.933192798731,
         0.6: 0.91924334076623,
         0.7: 0.90319951541439,
         0.8: 0.88493032977829,
         0.9: 0.86433393905362,
         1.0: 0.841344746069,
         1.1: 0.81582322731288,
         1.2: 0.78774581318061,
         1.3: 0.75798570450511,
         1.4: 0.72653065592704,
         1.5: 0.69314716055995,
         1.6: 0.65730019884867,
         1.7: 0.61839905914769,
         1.8: 0.57580633124096,
         1.9: 0.52892412654495,
         2.0: 0.47724986805182,
         2.1: 0.42074060762631,
         2.2: 0.35989164330376,
         2.3: 0.29505515613991,
         2.4: 0.22662735261643,
         2.5: 0.15597429781556,
         2.6: 0.08434363882874,
         2.7: 0.01390377072986,
         2.8: 0.00176703586613,
         2.9: 0.00023288832156,
         3.0: 0.00003167155677
    }

    # Flat arrays of the keys and values from the dictionary.
    zscore, prob_values = np.array(tuple(distribution.items())).T
    zscore_index = pd.Index(name='zscore', data=zscore)
    prob = pd.Series(name='prob', index=zscore_index, data=prob_values)
    return zscore, prob


def make_inputs(zscore: np.ndarray, prob: pd.Series) -> tuple[
    pd.DataFrame,  # demand_0
    pd.DataFrame,  # select_zscore
    pd.Series,     # coef
]:
    idx = pd.RangeIndex(name='id', start=1, stop=6)
    demand_0 = pd.DataFrame(
        data={
            'age':  (0.805262, 0.775366, 1.313498, 0.919934, 0.904917),
            'maritime': (True,    False,    False,     True,    False),
            'express': (False,    False,     True,    False,    False),
            'air':     (False,     True,    False,    False,     True),
            'percent_quotestage_1': (
                     0.728624, 0.987425, 1.083067, 0.353984, 0.529083),
        },
        index=idx,
    )

    # Select the zscore and its probability for every demand row based on a
    # binary selection variable. By this method, the distribution can be
    # arbitrary: non-linear and non-monotonic, so long as it's real. The
    # resulting frame is an ndemand by nzscore-values matrix.
    select_zscore = pd.DataFrame(
        pulp.LpVariable.matrix(name='zsel', cat=pulp.LpBinary, indices=(idx, zscore)),
        index=idx, columns=prob.index,
    )

    coef = pd.Series(
        name='coef', index=(*demand_0.columns, 'price'),
        data=(0.569396, -0.913858, -0.165595, 0.030166, 1.687747, -0.000523),
    )

    return demand_0, select_zscore, coef


def make_vars(
    demand_0: pd.DataFrame,
    zscore: np.ndarray,
    prob: pd.Series,
    select_zscore: pd.DataFrame,
    coef: pd.Series,
) -> pd.DataFrame:
    lp_vars = pd.DataFrame(
        data={
            # In the zscore expression, the first five terms are merged to one constant
            # per demand row.
            'fixed_factors': (demand_0 @ coef[demand_0.columns]).astype(float),

            # zscore is modelled as an affine expression calculated here as the matrix
            # product of all zscore selection variables and the zscore values vector.
            'zscore': select_zscore @ zscore,

            # Probability is the matrix product of the zscore selection variables and
            # the distribution probabilities. No zscore selection implies a zscore <
            # -3.4 and a probability of 0.
            'prob': select_zscore @ prob,

            # To get a binary value indicating whether the demand row is assigned, sum
            # all of its zscore selection variables.
            'assign': select_zscore.apply(pulp.lpSum, axis=1),

            # Expected price is a free variable, later constrained based on assignment.
            'expected_price': pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
                name='expected_price', cat=pulp.LpContinuous, indices=demand_0.index,
            ),
        },
        index=demand_0.index,
    )

    # The last term of zscore is based on a decision variable. To extract an
    # expression for the price, we calculate:
    # zscore = coef[:-1]@demand_0 + coef[-1]*price
    # price = (zscore - coef[:-1]@demand_0)/coef[-1]
    lp_vars['price'] = (
        lp_vars['zscore'] - lp_vars['fixed_factors']
    ) / coef['price']

    return lp_vars


def bound_expected_price(
    lp_vars: pd.DataFrame,
    zscore: np.ndarray,
    prob: pd.Series,
    coef: pd.Series,
) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    expected price <= price * prob
    but price and prob are all affine expressions based on the zscore selection
    decision variable.

    price = (zsel@zscore - demand0@coef)/coef_price
    eprice <= (zsel@zscore - demand0@coef)/coef_price * zsel@prob
           <= zsel@( (zscore - demand0@coef)/coef_price * prob)
           <= zsel@expected_price_bound

    expected_price_bound is an ndemands x nzscores constant matrix of bounds
    that, when selected, are the upper bound for the expected price.
    """
    return pd.DataFrame(
        data=(
             zscore - lp_vars['fixed_factors'].values[:, np.newaxis]
        ) / coef['price'] * prob.values,
        index=lp_vars.index, columns=zscore,
    )


def make_problem(expected_price: pd.Series) -> pulp.LpProblem:
    m = pulp.LpProblem(name='Optimize_Logistics_Prices', sense=pulp.LpMaximize)
    m.objective = expected_price.sum()
    return m


def add_constraints(
    m: pulp.LpProblem,
    lp_vars: pd.DataFrame,
    select_zscore: pd.DataFrame,
    expected_price_bound: pd.DataFrame,
    cost: float = 117.00,
    M: float = 10e6,
) -> None:
    for demand_id, row in lp_vars.iterrows():
        # The lower price constraint is only enforced if the demand row is
        # assigned
        m.addConstraint(
            name=f'price_{demand_id}',
            constraint=row['price'] >= cost - M*(1 - row['assign']),
        )

        # If the demand row is assigned, there is an upper bound on the
        # expected_price of price * prob.
        # If the demand row is not assigned, there is an upper bound of 0.
        # No lower bound needs to be set because the expected price is a
        # maximization objective.
        m.addConstraint(
            name=f'expprice_{demand_id}',
            constraint=row['expected_price'] <= pulp.lpDot(
                select_zscore.loc[demand_id, :],
                expected_price_bound.loc[demand_id, :],
            ),
        )

    for i, row in select_zscore.iterrows():
        # There must be at most one zscore selected per demand row.
        m.addConstraint(
            name=f'excl_{i}',
            constraint=pulp.lpSum(row) <= 1,
        )


def solve(m: pulp.LpProblem, lp_vars: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
    m.solve()
    if m.status != pulp.LpStatusOptimal:
        raise ValueError(m.status)

    affine_cols = ['price', 'zscore', 'prob', 'assign']
    lp_vars[affine_cols] = lp_vars[affine_cols].map(pulp.LpAffineExpression.value)
    lp_vars['expected_price'] = lp_vars['expected_price'].apply(pulp.LpVariable.value)


def main() -> None:
    zscore, prob = make_distribution()
    demand_0, select_zscore, coef = make_inputs(zscore, prob)
    lp_vars = make_vars(demand_0, zscore, prob, select_zscore, coef)
    expected_price = bound_expected_price(lp_vars, zscore, prob, coef)
    m = make_problem(lp_vars['expected_price'])
    add_constraints(m, lp_vars, select_zscore, expected_price, M=100e3, cost=6_500)
    print(m)

    solve(m, lp_vars)
    pd.options.display.max_columns = None
    pd.options.display.width = 200
    print(lp_vars)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
Optimize_Logistics_Prices:
MAXIMIZE
1*expected_price_1 + 1*expected_price_2 + 1*expected_price_3 + 1*expected_price_4 + 1*expected_price_5 + 0
SUBJECT TO
price_1: - 100000 zsel_1_0.0 - 100191.204589 zsel_1_0.1
 - 100382.409178 zsel_1_0.2 - 100573.613767 zsel_1_0.3
...

Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                1385.94715724
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               0
Time (CPU seconds):             0.01
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.01

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.01   (Wallclock seconds):       0.01

    fixed_factors  zscore      prob  assign  expected_price        price
id                                                                      
1        0.774388    -2.7  0.003289     1.0       21.852318  6643.189162
2        2.138180    -2.0  0.022750     1.0      180.007910  7912.389829
3        2.410249    -1.0  0.158655     1.0     1034.519800  6520.551792
4        0.207384     0.0  0.000000     0.0        0.000000   396.528057
5        1.438380    -2.0  0.022750     1.0      149.567130  6574.341044
```